# GetFeatureInfoUrl is not working

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I want to use GetFeatureInfo in WMS layer.  I have got some code but it shows only a blank window, and there is not​ any error.

This is the code link https://jsfiddle.net/seema30/LtcvhLwf/.

Comment: What request is actually generated by the code.  What do you get if you make the request in a browser

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you asking ,which request and how to see the browser request.Thank.

Comment: The purpose of your code is to generate a GetFeatureInfo request to send to some WMS server, then handle the response from that server in some popup

Comment: So the question is what actual request are you generating

Comment: If I click on map display the info about that clicked area.Thanks